# Python regular expression NoneType error

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I have a text file named "filename.txt"

content of file:

```
    This is just a text
    content to store
    in a file.
```

i have made two python scripts to extract "to" from the text file

my 1st script:

```
     #!/usr/bin/python
     import re
     f = open("filename.txt","r")
     for line in f:
              text = re.match(r"content (\S+) store",line)
              x = text.group(1)
              print x
```

my 2nd script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import re
    f = open("filename.txt","r")
    for line in f:
             text = re.match(r"content (\S+) store",line)
             if text:
                    x = text.group(1)
                    print x
```

2nd script gives the correct output

```
 bash-3.2$ ./script2.py
 to
```

but 1st script gives me an error

```
bash-3.2$ ./script1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./script1.py", line 6, in ?
x = text.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

how is that adding an "if" condition gives me the correct output and when i remove it i get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory to me: `re.match` returns `None` if no match is found (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)).

So when your regex doesn't match (eg first line), you're trying to access the `group` property of a `NoneType` object, it throws an error.

In the other case, you only access the property if `text` isn't `None` (since this is what the `if text:` checks, among other things).

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your first code, your regex fails to match anything and therefore `text` is a `NoneType`. When you try to do `group` it throws the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` error

However, for your regex, your code doesn't fail because you are careful to call `group` only if something was *actually* matched

Your second method is better since it's fail proof unlike the first one.